# Neither component in an ngIf statement are being shown even though one of them should be truey

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use an ngIf to hide the details of a component until the required variable has been set. While it's waiting it's supposed to show a loading message. I've tried googling for the answer and have come up blank.

The code for the component

```
export class PrintBookingComponent implements  AfterContentInit {
  private Interface: MSLZohoInterface | undefined;

  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    console.log("Initialising Print Booking");
    this.Interface = new MSLZohoInterface();
    var val = this.Interface.LoadBooking("4032446000000880091");
    if (val != undefined) {
      this.Booking = val;
      this.SelectedDate = this.Booking.Dates[0];
      //console.log(this.Booking);
    } else {
      this.Booking = <Booking>{};
    }
    this.HasBooking = true;
    //this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  }
  Booking: Booking | undefined;
  HasBooking: boolean = false;
  SelectedDate: PrintDate | undefined;

}
```

The HTML for the component

```
<ng-template *ngIf="Booking;">
  <H1>{{Booking.PrintBooking.Sales_Order.display_value}}</H1>
  <h2>{{Booking.PrintBooking.Account.display_value}} - {{Booking.PrintBooking.ContactID.display_value}}</h2>

  <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let d of Booking.Dates">
    <Button class="card-small" (click)="SelectedDate=(d)">
      {{d.publication}} - {{d.pubdate}}
    </Button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
<h1 *ngIf="!Booking;">Loading</h1>
<p>Print Component</p>
```

As you can see the code should be showing one or the other item, however when run it with ng serve I get this.
[image: Screen shot of screen output showing the text Print Component]

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really mean

```
<ng-template *ngIf="Booking;">
```

and not

```
<ng-container *ngIf="Booking;">
```

?

Comment: It was this, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the else logic Booking variable is assigned empty object

```
} else {
  this.Booking = <Booking>{};
}
```

So the Booking variable will always be true; Kindly add a logic to check property inside Booking. something like

```
<ng-template *ngIf="Booking.PrintBooking">Some content goes here</ng-template>
<h1 *ngIf="!Booking.PrintBooking">Loading</h1>
```

Also for variable initialisation part you can use

```
Booking: Booking | {};
```

Comment: I've just added <p>Booking Template</p> to the ng-template and it's not showing up. So I don't think it's an empty object problem.

Answer (score 0):

Angular's ng-template tag defines a template that is not rendered by default unless you tell angular to do so.
Thats why in your case content inside ng-template is not showing up. So what i did is i instructed angular to show ng-template content by defining an 'else' statement in *ngIf.

```
<h1 *ngIf="!Booking;else bookingtemplate">Loading</h1>
    <p>Print Component</p> 
   <ng-template #bookingtemplate>
      <H1>{{Booking.PrintBooking.Sales_Order.display_value}}</H1>
      <h2>{{Booking.PrintBooking.Account.display_value}} - {{Booking.PrintBooking.ContactID.display_value}}</h2>
    
      <div class="card-container" *ngFor="let d of Booking.Dates">
        <Button class="card-small" (click)="SelectedDate=(d)">
          {{d.publication}} - {{d.pubdate}}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```